# The derivative of a matrix transpose with respect to the original matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I am just stepping into matrix calculus and I wonder what the following differential is. Thanks.

$$ \frac{\partial(A^T)}{\partial A} $$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: Just used mathJax

Comment: This is an interesting question. Similar questions have appeared; I'll see if I can find one.

Comment: We need to choose a linear tranformation $D$ such that 

$$0\leftarrow\frac{\left\|(A+B)^T-A^{T}-D(B)\right\|}{\left\|B\right\|}=\frac{\left\|B^T-D(B)\right\|}{\left\|B\right\|}$$

as $\left\|B\right\|\to0$

The linear transformation $\cdot^T:\mathbb{K}^{\text{size}(A)}\to\mathbb{K}^{\text{size}(A^T)}$ that takes $A\mapsto A^T$ clearly does the job, since we get 

$$\frac{\left\|B^T-D(B)\right\|}{\left\|B\right\|}=\frac{\left\|B^T-B^T\right\|}{\left\|B\right\|}=0$$

This shouldn't be a surprise. In general, the differential of a linear transformation, is itself.

Answer (score 2):

The transposition of a $3 \times 2$ matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12}\\ x_{21} & x_{22}\\ x_{31} & x_{32}\\ \end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{21} & x_{31}\\ x_{12} & x_{22} & x_{32}\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence,

$$\dfrac{\partial x_{11}}{\partial \mathrm X} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix} \qquad \qquad \dfrac{\partial x_{21}}{\partial \mathrm X} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix} \qquad \qquad \dfrac{\partial x_{31}}{\partial \mathrm X} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\dfrac{\partial x_{12}}{\partial \mathrm X} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix} \qquad \qquad \dfrac{\partial x_{22}}{\partial \mathrm X} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix} \qquad \qquad \dfrac{\partial x_{32}}{\partial \mathrm X} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo, can this be generalized to a solution of the a matrix with the same dimension as the original matrix and all entries equal to 1?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If all entries are $1$, why differentiate?

Answer (score 0):

The gradient $\,\,{\mathcal H}=\frac{\partial A^T}{\partial A}\,\,$ is a fourth order tensor whose components are given by 
$$\eqalign{
{\mathcal H}_{ijkl}
 &= \frac{\partial A^T_{ij}}{\partial A_{kl}} = \frac{\partial A_{ji}}{\partial A_{kl}} \,\,\,= \delta_{jk}\,\delta_{il} \cr
}$$
where the Kronecker delta has components 
$$\delta_{jk}= \begin{cases}1 &\text{if}\,\,\,\,j=k \\ 0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$